# GraphQLTestCase self.query query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'op_name'

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I have the following `GraphQLTestCase`

```
def test_create_foo(self):
    response = self.query(
        """
        mutation createFoo($input: MutationInput!) {
            createFoo(input: $input) {
                foo {
                    id
                    title
                }
            }
        }
        """,
        op_name="createFoo",
        input_data={"title": "Title Test"},
    )
```

When I ran, I got the error:

> response = self.query(
> TypeError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'op_name'

I am using:

- graphene 3.1.1
- graphene-django 3.0.0

What can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently `op_name` argument was renamed to `operation_name` in `graphene-django 3.0.0`, you can check other changes here https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/releases/tag/v3.0.0